# xfce wont launch diodon via shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce

I'm running XFCE on 16.04, and have installed diodon.

I have set-up a system-wide keyboard shortcut as it says [here](https://esite.ch/2015/07/using-custom-shortcuts-of-de-as-diodon-hotkey/), but diodon history wont launch.

[image: shortcut settings]

(I have tried both diodon (which works when using alt+f2) and /usr/bin/diodon to no effect; diodon is running and accessible in the tray area)

If I launch it manually using `ALT-F2`, it displays history correctly. If I change the `ctrl+alt+v` shortcut to another application (e.g., firefox), the shortcut works correctly. But I set up diodon and history doesn't open, nor it display any kind of error.

I have also tried upgrading to diodon 1.5, just in case.

Any idea of what's going on?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What's the command you put in xfce shortcuts? Picture not big enough.

Comment: Also the official xfce clipboard is Clipman.

Comment: The command is "diodon"

Comment: No, it's not... The blog entry clearly states what the command needs to be

Comment: Tried with /usr/bin/diodon. Same thing.

Comment: And alt+f2 and just "diodon" works

Comment: Diodon needs to be running first, is it?

Comment: It is, of course.

Comment: Then you'll need to figure out what's the "custom shortcut"equivalent of gnome for xfce or use Clipman as I suggested the very first time.

Comment: I personally think you're confusing the shortcut app with the paste history shortcut and putting "diodon" as an order won't open your paste history ever.